# Kurento service not listing custom filter .so file

Tags: gstreamer, kurento, .so

I have created a custom filter for Kurento Media Server using gstreamer.
as per the documentation I have created the .deb file `debuild -us -uc` and installed it because of which the `libkmscustomfiltermodule.so` is generated at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kurento/modules/`

Initially it was listed in the loaded modules but I deleted this `.so` and after this its not listed (`sudo  kurento-media-server --list`)

even if I revert my changes and restart the `kurent-media-server-6.0` service, this `customfilter` is not being listed in `sudo  kurento-media-server --list`

in server logs I see this log:

```
ModuleManager.cpp:61 loadModule()  Module /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kurento/modules/libkmscustomfiltermodule.so cannot be loaded:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmscustomfilterimpl.so.0: undefined symbol: _ZN7kurento6module15customfilter19CustomFilterImpl4loopE
```

any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your module has some symbols missing.

To detect this errors, it's a good practice to create a test that tries to load the module and instantiate classes in there. This way you know if your module is build correctly before trying it in the mediaserver.

This test is done in kms-elements, you can use it as an example:

https://github.com/Kurento/kms-elements/blob/master/tests/server/constructors.cpp

Comment: this load module error occurs when I insert gstreamer related code, if I remove GStreamer related code then  the code works fine. is there any specific version of gstremer required in kurento ?

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal If the error started happening when you added gstreamer stuff, maybe you are missing some to add some library while compiling. I seems that the missing symbol is loop, but without seeing the code I cannot tell you where it is defined.

Comment: I will post the code in some time, meanwhile I am getting compile time error cant locate `config.h` can you tell which `config.h` is required here

Comment: the error was related to `GMainLoop *loop` once I commented this code its working fine now, any idea why there is a linking error for `GMainLoop`, also do I need a loop on active media pipeline ?

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal There is no need to hava a GMainLoop in your code only if your logic requires it.

`config.h` is generated from `config.h.cmake` using proper configuraiton in `CMakeLists.txt`. See this example: https://github.com/Kurento/kms-pointerdetector/blob/master/config.h.cmake https://github.com/Kurento/kms-pointerdetector/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L50

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal You have got an example of this in zbar example https://github.com/Kurento/kms-filters/blob/master/src/server/implementation/objects/ZBarFilterImpl.cpp#L61

This elements posts messages on the bus and the c++ API converts them on events.

Comment: okay, I will take a look into this example.. will get back to you soon... thanks & happy coding